# .NET version in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, .net-4.6

What is the difference between .NET Framework Version

> 4.6.01038

and

> 4.6.01055

Both VS installs have Update 3, first one is Windows 10, second one is Windows 7. I assume both refer to .NET 4.6.1 but why is there a version difference?

There are also differences in C# and F# keys, `AA015` and `AA499`.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Unless you are raising a support case with Microsoft, such information rarely matters. Tiny differences are known majorly by Microsoft, as there would be no documentation to cover them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that comes from the version installed on your machine. On my computer, the .Net version displayed in the Visual Studio about box matches the version displayed in Control Panel >> Programs and Features.

You can also check your Windows registry to confirm the installed version:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/318785

In your case, my guess is you have a later revision of 4.6 installed (01055) on your Windows 7 OS than the one on your Windows 10 OS (01038).

As far as your Visual Studio keys, I think when you activate Visual Studio on a machine it generates a specific key tied to your particular system. Not super familiar in that department though so maybe someone else can elaborate on that. Hope this helps!  :)

Comment: Will check registry as per your suggestion. I would've thought that installing Update 3 would lead to the same .Net version on both PCs.

Comment: It is possible they have slightly different build versions due to differences in the OS or KB application(s) from Windows Update.

Comment: Btw, I checked the registry and on the windows 10 PC registry shows 01055 and VS shows different version. On win7 these match.